# total sum using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I am new to android and I am having problems with getting total amount greater than date('now'). I am storing date as INTEGER in sqlite database and my amount column as Real. I am taking date from DatePicker and converting it to milliseconds using

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

year  = selectedYear;
month = selectedMonth;
day   = selectedDay;
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
long dateInMillis=c.getTime().getTime();//I am putting this variable into date column in sqlite
```

here is my query

```
String selectTotalAmountQuery = "select sum(amount) as total from entry where"+          "d_date>date('now')";//entry is my table name
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectTotalAmountQuery, null);
double amount=0;

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    amount = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("total"));

    Log.i("TotalAmount :",amount+"");
    c.close();
}
db.close();
```

Log output is
    TotalAmount : 0.0

I know there can be other ways of doing this without using date function But I want to know if this is possible using date('now') function??

Answer (score 0):

The date function in Sqlite returns a 'YYYY-MM-DD' string format, so it is not returning the milliseconds, only the date part not time.

[Date Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

One solution is to get the current milliseconds from the java code and pass it in the query.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite's [date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) returns a string in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

To get a number that is compatible with the values in your `d_date` column, use `strftime` to get the number of seconds since the epoch, and convert it to milliseconds:

```
... WHERE d_date > 1000 * strftime('%s', 'now', 'start of day')
```

Comment: It worked ! I can vote up your answer as my reputation is below 15 but  once I exceep reputation of 15 I will vote your answer up.Thank you